# Are there any ML/NLP works/papers on parsing/solving math word problems?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

As the title says, any pointers are much appreciated.

I am exploring, where do we stand in terms of ML/NLP efforts, in context of solving (to begin with - parsing) Math Word Problems.

We have decent enough softwares in likes of Mathematica which can solve well formulated math equations.

But when it comes to solving math problems expressed in natural languages, I could not find anything substantial.
When I think about how to approach this, I see it as a sort of Machine Translation problem (translating from English to Math-equations), but there is hardly any 'labeled' data for that. Other approach can be semi (or un) sypervised Relation Extraction.

Since these are just random thoughts, I want to start with some existing work/papers in this direction. My otherwise decent googling skills, didn't help much.

Comment: I think the reverse problem will be more interesting. Improving current Natural Language Understanding algorithms using word problems as training data.

Comment: Looks like somebody already did it http://economictimes.indiatimes.com/industry/et-cetera/new-computer-system-solves-algebra-word-problems/articleshow/34682412.cms

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any work that parses language into mathematical expressions: the closest I can think of is semantic parsing, where the goal is to translate text into logical forms. There are [supervised attempts](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/~ml/publications/area/77/learning_for_semantic_parsing) at this, but I suspect you're right to say that there is no labelled data available. You could consider an [unsupervised variant](http://homes.cs.washington.edu/~pedrod/papers/emnlp09.pdf) too.

I think your intuition that it's similar to machine translation is partly correct, and indeed alignment techniques would form one half of the solution. The other half is what would replace your target language model, which is an interesting problem for mathematics since you'd be looking to determine whether the resulting mathematical expression was "well-formed" or meaningful.

I hope that's of some use, and sorry I couldn't point to anything on your specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Wolfram|Alpha are some way along with this, but I don't know what papers are driving the progress they have made. You can check it out [here](http://blog.wolframalpha.com/2012/10/04/solving-word-problems-with-wolframalpha/)